# Visual Studio 2012 TSQL-XML in Results window

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, visual-studio-2012

I am running simple XML queries in TSQL:

```
SELECT    
   c.CustomerID AS "@CustomerID"
   ,oh.CustomerID
   ,oh.SalesOrderID
   ,oh.Status 
FROM 
   Sales.Customer c 
INNER JOIN 
   Sales.SalesOrderHeader oh ON c.CustomerID = oh.CustomerID
FOR XML  PATH ('Customer'), ROOT ('Customer')
```

BUT the results windows displays non-hierarchically displayed XML data:

```
XML_F52E2B61-18A1-.....
<Customer><Customer CustomerID="29825"><CustomerID>29825</CustomerID><SalesOrderID>43659</SalesOrderID><Status>5</Status></Customer>
```

Is there a way to direct the results window to display it hierarchically/nested elements style?

Comment: Can you show us what you would like to get instead of what you have now?

Comment: marc_s, when i ran the SQL below, the Results window displayed all the XML elements on a single line (either as text or grid format). But it seems from your example, you are able to render the results in the Visual Studio Results window with each element on its own line (?). is there a setting in VStudio i need to change? Or are the results, all elements as one line, the default behavior?

Comment: Just **click on that XML** in one line! It will expand into a separate window

Comment: thanks marc_s! i had no idea it was that simple! And yes, i feel embarrassed that i seem so stupid to not have seen or thought of doing that. Learning how to use a tool can sometimes go like that. thanks once again!!!

Answer (score 0):

You're not very clear on what you're trying to get - I'm *guessing* you might want to have the orders contained below each `<Customer>` node. IF that's the case - use a SQL statement something like this:

```
SELECT    
   c.CustomerID AS '@CustomerID',
   (SELECT
       oh.SalesOrderID, oh.Status 
    FROM
       Sales.SalesOrderHeader oh 
    WHERE 
       c.CustomerID = oh.CustomerID
    FOR XML PATH('Order'), TYPE) AS Orders
FROM 
   Sales.Customer c 
WHERE
   EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh WHERE c.CustomerID = soh.CustomerID)
FOR XML PATH ('Customer'), ROOT ('Customers')
```

to get an output something like this:

```
<Customers>
  <Customer CustomerID="11000">
    <Orders>
      <Order>
        <SalesOrderID>43793</SalesOrderID>
        <Status>5</Status>
      </Order>
      <Order>
        <SalesOrderID>51522</SalesOrderID>
        <Status>5</Status>
      </Order>
      <Order>
        <SalesOrderID>57418</SalesOrderID>
        <Status>5</Status>
      </Order>
    </Orders>
  </Customer>
  <Customer CustomerID="11001">
    <Orders>
      <Order>
        <SalesOrderID>43767</SalesOrderID>
        <Status>5</Status>
      </Order>
      <Order>
        <SalesOrderID>51493</SalesOrderID>
        <Status>5</Status>
      </Order>
      <Order>
        <SalesOrderID>72773</SalesOrderID>
        <Status>5</Status>
      </Order>
    </Orders>
  </Customer>
  <Customer CustomerID="11002">
  .....
</Customers>
```

Comment: I suspect their issue was about it all appearing on one line rather than being nicely formatted and separated onto separate lines - but your edit of the question has made that rather "difficult" to observe.